# Cannot pass null to server using jQuery AJAX. Value received at the server is the string "null"

Tags: jquery, ajax, null

I am converting a javascript/php/ajax application to use jQuery to ensure compatibility with browsers other than Firefox.

I am having trouble passing true, false, and null values using jQuery's ajax function.

Javascript code:

```
$.ajax
(
   {
      url     : <server_url>,
      dataType: 'json',
      type    : 'POST',
      success : receiveAjaxMessage,
      data:
      {
         valueTrue : true,
         valueFalse: false,
         valueNull : null
      }
   }
);
```

PHP code:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Server output:

```
array(3) {
  ["valueTrue"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  ["valueFalse"]=>
  string(5) "false"
  ["valueNull"]=>
  string(4) "null"
}
```

The problem is that the null, true, and false values are being converted to strings.

The Javascript AJAX code currently in use passes null, true, and false correctly but only works in Firefox.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem using jQuery?

---

Here is some working code (not using jQuery) to compare with the not-working code given above.

Javascript Code:

```
ajaxPort.send
(
   <server_url>,
   {
      valueTrue : true,
      valueFalse: false,
      valueNull : null
   }
);
```

PHP code:

```
var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true));
```

Server output:

```
array(3) {
  ["valueTrue"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["valueFalse"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["valueNull"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Note that the null, true, and false values are correctly received.

Note also that in the second method the $_POST array is not used in the PHP code.  I think this is the key to the problem, but I cannot find a way to replicate this behavior using jQuery.

---

This section was added after the answer below was accepted.

Here is a corrected version of the original code.

Javascript code:

```
$.ajax
(
   {
      url     : <server_url>,
      dataType: 'json',
      type    : 'POST',
      success : receiveAjaxMessage,
      data    : JSON.stringify
      (
         {
            valueTrue : true,
            valueFalse: false,
            valueNull : null
         }
      )
   }
);
```

PHP code:

```
var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true));
```

Server output:

```
array(3) {
  ["valueTrue"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["valueFalse"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["valueNull"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong but is your data valid JSON? Shouldn't all key/values be enclosed in "" ?it might not solve your problem but if you stringify your data and just pass an empty string for the null value then I think it might work? I have a feeling jquery is wrapping your data in the "" so the value you are sending to the server is actuall a string containing the text null, like this: "null".

Comment: Thanks for replying Danny, but I am certain that true, false, and null may be used unquoted in JSON.  See www.json.org.

Comment: You were probably right, but I misunderstood you.  Stringifying the data at the Javascript side solved the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What would you expect? You are sending this values as POST parameters, which are simple text strings. If you want type-safe transfer, use some sort of encoding, such as JSON. (Which is not what `dataType` does - that refers to the response from the server.)

Comment: Thank you.  Encoding the data as JSON fixed the problem.  I misunderstood the purpose of the 'dataType' option.

Answer (score 12):

You can use **undefined** instead of **null**.

```
data: {
  valueTrue : true,
  valueFalse: false,
  valueNull : undefined
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone that comes across this, the bug is fixed in jQuery 1.8

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/714

Answer (score 1):

I would expect it to send query params as valueNull= rather than valueNull=null which is my experience.

If you are doing REST with JSON you still need to send query params for GETS and you must not convert all your GETS to POSTS to get round this issue.