# Flipping An Array without removing unique keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to set user permissions, they are stored as an array in the database.. This is the current output from my html form...

```
{
"where_to_buy": "true",
"spec_sheet": "true",
"dwg_access": "true",
"bim_access": "true",
"product_prices": "true",
"portal_access": "true",
"save_quote": "true",
"request_drawings": "true",
"place_order": "true",
"special_offer": "true"
}
```

However I need it to be formatted like so:

```
{
"where_to_buy": true,
"spec_sheet": true,
"dwg_access": true,
"bim_access": true,
"product_prices": true,
"portal_access": true,
"save_quote": true,
"request_drawings": true,
"place_order": true,
"special_offer": true
}
```

How do I stop or convert my html form submission from strings to just true or false values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bool parameter from jQuery Ajax received as literal string "false"/"true" in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408976/bool-parameter-from-jquery-ajax-received-as-literal-string-false-true-in-php)

Comment: I somehow miss the connection between the question title and text....

Comment: You already store those strings as strings in the database? Please elaborate.

Comment: I kind of mixed up the question title with something else, sorry! I'll change it if I can.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `json_decode` along with `array_map` like as

```
echo json_encode(array_map(function($v) {
        if ($v == "true") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }, json_decode($json, true)));
```

Comment: unconditionally `return true`? That may be ok for the sample object but the question text suggests there can be true _and_ false values.

Comment: `echo json_encode(array_map(function($v){ return $v == "true"; },json_decode($json,true)));`

Comment: I've updated my answer @VolkerK I've didn't checked that line. Thanks for pointing out that too..

Answer (score 1):

You can map values with [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

This also allows you to add more than true/false if required later

```
// from json   
$yourArray = json_decode($yourJSON, true);

// map values
array_walk($yourArray, function(&$v) {
    $map = array(
        'true' => true,
        'false' => false
        // more as needed
    );

    if ( isset($map[$v]) ) {
        $v = $map[$v];
    }
});

// back to json
$output = json_encode($yourArray);
```

Edit: both at once, see comments

```
$yourArray = json_decode($yourJSON, true);
$yourFormattedArray = array();
$map = array(
    'true' => true,
    'false' => false
    // more as needed
);

foreach ($yourArray as $key => $val ) {
    if ( isset($map[$val]) ) {
        $val = $map[$val];
    }
    $yourFormattedArray[str_replace('_', '.', $key)] = $val;
}

$yourFinalArray = json_encode($yourFormattedArray);
```

Comment: Facepalm. Totally missed that, title threw me - thanks. Added encode/decode

Comment: Your original code worked fine for me..

The new problem is that I need to have "."'s in the array keys instead of "_".... Apparently you can't name your form inputs with .'s it willl just convert them to _'s anyway. I didn't notice at first that they weren't "."'s.

Comment: That's really a seperate question, but I've added it for you